# Was Boba Fett ever motivated by revenge for his father's death?

Tags: star-wars

Boba Fett witnessed his "father" Jango being killed by Jedi Master Mace Windu.

Is there any indication in canon (any level including EU) that any of his actions in life was **explicitly** motivated by a desire for revenge for that event?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### In Disney Canon, Boba Fett tried to avenge his father's death by killing Windu with a bomb.

This occurs in the *Clone Wars* episode *Death Trap* (S02E20). In this episode, Fett is explicitly attempting to kill Windu, and has no other mission or instruction from outside parties.

The [official synopsis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Trap) reads:

> A young boy wages war against the Jedi Knights who left him orphaned, bitter and alone.

From [StarWars.com](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/death-trap-episode-guide):

> Determined to kill Jedi Master Mace Windu, young Boba Fett poses as a clone cadet and sneaks aboard a Jedi cruiser to plant a bomb in Windu's quarters. But Boba's plan goes awry when the blast fails to kill Mace and, suddenly, every clone aboard is looking for the saboteur. Boba destroys the ship's reactor to create a distraction and, soon, the entire cruiser begins to break apart. Unaware that Boba is the culprit, Boba's new cadet comrades save his life but is he too obsessed with revenge to do the same for them?

[image: boba just wants to murder. won't someone think of the boba?]